# Convert a class to an extended class (php)

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have a wrapper over the mysqli_stmt class, but I don't know how to convert the normal statement to my extended class.

Basically, I have something like `class MyPreparedStatement extends mysqli_stmt { ... }`
and I want when I create a statement to use my class. Something like: `$stmt = (MyPreparedStatement) $connection->prepare($query);`

Is this possible? Or I have to change my logic and use it another way? Thanks.

Comment: You could simply creat an instance of your class `$conn = new MyPreparedStatement()` and then call the method from your class: `$conn->prepare()`. Your question isn't very clear

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast in that way. You'll need to pass it to an intermediary method first or just wrap mysqli and then your methods can return whichever objects you wish.